# Is "what" a subordinating conjunction?

Tags: conjunctions, what

For example in this sentence:

> What the knowledge of Grammar facilitates is further learning of English itself

And, what type of Subordinate Clause is "the knowledge of Grammar facilitates"?

Comment: Some dictionaries consider it a conjunction, others would classify it as a pronoun.

Comment: What is your understanding of a subordinating conjunction? Why do you think "what" is/isn't one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of the fused relative construction. *What* plays the part of both the relativised element and relative word.

Compare:

*That [which the knowledge of grammar facilitates ___] is further learning of English itself.*

*[What the knowledge of grammar facilitates ___] is further learning of English itself.*

In the first sentence, *that*, a pronoun, is the object of *facilitates* , and *which*, a relative pronoun, is the relative word. In the second sentence *what* is both object of *facilitates* and the relative word.

*What* introduces a relative clause, one sort of subordinate clause. Since there is a gap in the clause it introduces, this construction differs from other constructions involving subordinate clauses.

So, to get back to the original question, *what* is a fused-head relative word in your example.